# iOS6 update to 8 or greater

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, macos

I have an iPhone with `iOS 6.0.1`. I need to update it to `iOS 8` or later. I also have a MacBook Pro with `macOS Sierra v 10.12.5`.

**Problem**

My MacBook has `Thunderbolt 3` ports, and no `usb` ports. My old iPhone only has a `usb` cable. (I don't have a `Thunderbolt 3` to `usb` adapter).

**Question**

Is it possible to upgrade the firmware on the old iPhone given my situation?

I have tried via bluetooth, I can get the devices to pair, but then don't see the iPhone in my MacBooks iTunes.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hi Richard, and welcome to Ask different! Please add what version of iPhone you have (ie 5S, 6+, etc). Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jackson, It's an `iPhone 3GS`. (`Model MC132B`)

Comment: Looks like `iOS6` is the latest version available on the `iPhone 3GS` unfortunately.

Comment: I am trying to test an app I developed. Usually you would download `Test Flight` to download your app in a test sandbox. `Test Flight` requires at least `iOS8`. So I have a problem obviously. Is there any way I can download and test my app on the `iPhone 3GS`?

Comment: No, sorry. iPhone 3GS cannot run iOS 8. You need to buy a new iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

### You can't.

Due to the limitations of the iPhone 3GS and the design of Apple's iOS, you are unable to update any iPhone 3GS past iOS 6.1.6.

The only way you will be able to test you app is using the iOS simulator on your computer, or using a different iPhone.

In addition, it appears that you will no longer be able to upload 32-bit apps to the App Store, and the 3GS is a 32-bit device. Sorry!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Looks like I need to borrow a friends iPhone.

Comment: @Richard - It looks like you made two accounts... You should probably switch to the one that you asked with so you can consolidate rep from question upvotes and also select an answer as the solution. There's also a slight chance your accounts are targeted for suspicious activity if you maintain two.